# How to put sets of buttons side by side below text fields?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put two sets (one with two buttons and one with only one button) of buttons side by side. However, one of my buttons is in a form, so I don't know how to do it.

This is the HTML code:

```html
<ion-content padding>


  <div class="logo">
    <div class="logo-icon">
      <img src="{{logo}}">
    </div>
  </div>

  <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="loginUser()" novalidate>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-input formControlName="email" type="email" placeholder="Email address" [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls.email.valid && loginForm.controls.email.dirty"></ion-input>
      <ion-icon name="ios-mail-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="error-message" *ngIf="!loginForm.controls.email.valid  && loginForm.controls.email.dirty">
      <p>Please enter a valid email.</p>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-input formControlName="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls.password.valid && loginForm.controls.password.dirty"></ion-input>
      <ion-icon name="ios-key-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="error-message" *ngIf="!loginForm.controls.password.valid  && loginForm.controls.password.dirty">
      <p>Your password needs more than 6 characters.</p>
    </ion-item>

    <button ion-button block type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
          Login
        </button>

  </form>

  <button ion-button block clear (click)="goToSignup()">
        New account
      </button>

  <button ion-button block clear (click)="goToResetPassword()">
        Forgot password
      </button>


  <button ion-button block class="facebook-btn" (click)="facebookLogin()">
         <ion-icon name="logo-facebook" class="icons"> </ion-icon>
          Login with Facebook</button>

  <button ion-button block class="google-btn" (click)="googleLogin()">
         <ion-icon name="logo-google" class="icons"></ion-icon>
          Login with Google</button>

</ion-content>
```

[This is how I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS5hO.png)

EDIT:
Forgot the CSS:

```
page-login {

  background-size: 100%;
  background-position-y: 50%;

  .logo {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .facebook-btn {
    background-color: #939393;
    margin: auto;
    width: 55%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
      height: 5%;
  }

  .google-btn {
    background-color: #939393;
    margin: auto;
    width: 55%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
     height: 5%;
  }

  .norm-login-textfield{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
      height: 5%;
  }

  .norm-login-field{
    background-color: #909090;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 55%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
     height: 5%;
  }

  .icons{
       margin-right: 10px;
  }

  .error {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(217, 74, 87);
    p {
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }

  .invalid {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FF6153;
  }

  ion-input {
    padding: 5px;
  }


}
```

THIS IS HOW IT LOOKS LIKE WITH THE SUGGESTED SOLUTION:
[Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsUyC.png)

This is the new HTML code:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="logo-icon">
      <img src="{{logo}}">
    </div>
  </div>

  <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="loginUser()" novalidate>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-input formControlName="email" type="email" placeholder="Email address" [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls.email.valid && loginForm.controls.email.dirty"></ion-input>
      <ion-icon name="ios-mail-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="error-message" *ngIf="!loginForm.controls.email.valid  && loginForm.controls.email.dirty">
      <p>Please enter a valid email.</p>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-input formControlName="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls.password.valid && loginForm.controls.password.dirty"></ion-input>
      <ion-icon name="ios-key-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="error-message" *ngIf="!loginForm.controls.password.valid  && loginForm.controls.password.dirty">
      <p>Your password needs more than 6 characters.</p>
    </ion-item>

    <button ion-button block type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" style="float:left;width:100px;height:50px;background:orange;color:white">
          Login
        </button>

  </form>
  <div id="btn">
    <button ion-button clear (click)="goToSignup()" style="float:left;">
        New account
      </button>

    <button ion-button (click)="goToResetPassword()">
        Forgot password
      </button>
  </div>

  <button ion-button block class="facebook-btn" (click)="facebookLogin()">
         <ion-icon name="logo-facebook" class="icons"> </ion-icon>
          Login with Facebook</button>

  <button ion-button block class="google-btn" (click)="googleLogin()">
         <ion-icon name="logo-google" class="icons"></ion-icon>
          Login with Google</button>

</ion-content>
```

CSS:

```
page-login {

  background-size: 100%;
  background-position-y: 50%;

  .logo {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  button {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 7px;
  border: none;
}

#btn button {
  padding: 3px;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#btn {
  overflow: hidden;
}

  .facebook-btn,
.google-btn {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  border: none;
  background: #939393;
}

  .norm-login-textfield{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
      height: 5%;
  }

  .norm-login-field{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 55%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
     height: 5%;
  }

  .icons{
       margin-right: 10px;
  }

  .error {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(217, 74, 87);
    p {
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }

  .invalid {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FF6153;
  }

button {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 7px;
  border: none;
}
  #btn button {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#btn {
  overflow: hidden;
}

  ion-input {
    padding: 5px;
  }


}
```

Comment: paste the code you have tried. Then we will answer rectifying the issues in your code.!

Comment: You don't have any CSS code ?

Comment: X2 columns: #1 for the Login button, #2 for the account action links. Ensure that columns are within the `form` element. That'll be your structure. The rest is just styling and should be smooth sailing (there are so many examples online to demonstrate this).

Comment: @JithinRajPR: It is the code I have tried with.

Comment: @Core972: I have edited my question. I forgot it completely

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```css
button {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 7px;
  border: none;
}

.facebook-btn,
.google-btn {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  border: none;
  background: grey;
}

#btn button {
  padding: 3px;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  background: #ddd;
}

#btn {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="logo-icon">
      <img src="{{logo}}">
    </div>
  </div>

  <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="loginUser()" novalidate>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-input formControlName="email" type="email" placeholder="Email address" [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls.email.valid && loginForm.controls.email.dirty"></ion-input>
      <ion-icon name="ios-mail-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="error-message" *ngIf="!loginForm.controls.email.valid  && loginForm.controls.email.dirty">
      <p>Please enter a valid email.</p>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-input formControlName="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls.password.valid && loginForm.controls.password.dirty"></ion-input>
      <ion-icon name="ios-key-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="error-message" *ngIf="!loginForm.controls.password.valid  && loginForm.controls.password.dirty">
      <p>Your password needs more than 6 characters.</p>
    </ion-item>

    <button ion-button block type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" style="float:left;width:100px;height:50px;background:orange;color:white">
          Login
        </button>

  </form>
  <div id="btn">
    <button ion-button clear (click)="goToSignup()" style="float:left;">
        New account
      </button>

    <button ion-button (click)="goToResetPassword()">
        Forgot password
      </button>
  </div>

  <button ion-button block class="facebook-btn" (click)="facebookLogin()">
         <ion-icon name="logo-facebook" class="icons"> </ion-icon>
          Login with Facebook</button>

  <button ion-button block class="google-btn" (click)="googleLogin()">
         <ion-icon name="logo-google" class="icons"></ion-icon>
          Login with Google</button>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: what you say i dont understand